# Why we have used pointer in this C program?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why we have used pointer in this C code? Basically, I am just searching a string in the array, but without pointer, it is unable to run. But why is that?

```
int main() {

    char *x[] = {"ab", "bc", "cd", 0};

    char *s = "ab";

    int i = 0;

    while(x[i]) {

            if(strcmp(x[i], s) == 0) {
                    printf("Gotcha!\n");
                    break;
            }

            i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do that doesn't work? Without what pointer?

Comment: How would I know why you used pointers in some code that you wrote?  I can't read your mind. Perhaps you want to rephrase your question.

Comment: Almost all array manipulation in C is done via pointers, explicitly or implicitly. Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: I have no idea why you have used a pointer in that C code.  You need to be clear about what you expect to happen, what is happening and why you believe that's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying:

```
char x[] = ...
```

This is an array of chars, meaning only one character. The pointer allows multiple characters per item in the array.

The pointer is necessary in the way the program is created because the char data type cannot refer to the amount of chars needed. The next best data type for pure C is a char *, which can *reference* multiple chars.

Comment: a char\* does *not* hold multiple chars.

Comment: Feel free to edit @immibis

Answer (score 0):

*Strings* are a surprisingly complex matter *under the hood*. C decided to just ignore all complexity coming with strings by not supporting them as a type. There's a type `char` for a single *character* and a string is just a pointer to the first element of an array of characters. The end of the string is marked by the first `'\0'` character (a 0 byte).

So, short story: you handle strings, you need pointers (to characters, that is ...).

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a string in a string array.
1.So,for string s,we use a pointer to first character of the string. You CAN represent using array if you want, just remember about null termination. 
2.As for the string array c, it is implemented here by pointer to the first string(char array). Incrementing the pointer checks all the strings till the last string, where it becomes null. 
If you want, you can replace it with 2d array, but you have to know the max string size beforehand and resize the array if it becomes too big. Generally char pointers are the  <strike>easiest</strike> least painful way to handle strings in c .